# All letters R in construcnions R.id.name became red

Tags: android-studio, android-resources

After connection FireBase all letters R in constructions R.id.name became red. Task clean project doesn`t help. Deleting directories build/ doesn`t help also. 
in log is written error: attribute 'e.android.myapp:adSize' not found.
Please, advice me, how can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

R is the main Resource.java which keeps a map of all allocations whichever you make in your app. It is deleted by its own if something is wrong in any of you .xml files, whether it is drawable, or layout, or any other res files.
the attribute adSize is not allowed in whichever layout tag you are trying to add. if its prefix is `android:adSize` try changing it to `app:adSize` and auto import app namespace. Rebuild your project, and it will regenerate your R.java file.
Happy coding...